# Understand login logout events on SQL Server extended events after upgrading compatibility level

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

After upgrading the compatibility level of our SQL Server to 150, we're facing some random issues getting the SCOPE_IDENTITY after an INSERT. To find the issue, we create an event session like this :

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [QuickSessionTSQL] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported(
    ACTION(package0.callstack,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.tsql_stack)
    WHERE ([severity]>=(20) OR ([error_number]=(17803) OR [error_number]=(701) OR [error_number]=(802) OR [error_number]=(8645) OR [error_number]=(8651) OR [error_number]=(8657) OR [error_number]=(8902) OR [error_number]=(41354) OR [error_number]=(41355) OR [error_number]=(41367) OR [error_number]=(41384) OR [error_number]=(41336) OR [error_number]=(41309) OR [error_number]=(41312) OR [error_number]=(41313)))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.existing_connection(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.session_id)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.login(SET collect_options_text=(1)
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.session_id)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.logout(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.session_id)),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_starting(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0)))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_starting(
    ACTION(package0.event_sequence,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0))))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=16384 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=5 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=PER_CPU,TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

And we see our INSERT statements and the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY but with strange behavior. Depending on the sqlserver.session_id, we notice one **logout** event and one **login** event after each SQL statement. Whereas on the other sqlserver.session_id we just see the usual statements.

First scenario (the good one) :

- session_id : 10
- INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES....
- SELECT SCOPE_IDENTIY()...
- INSERT INTO MyOtherTable...

The second scenario (the bad one) :

- session_id : 98
- login
- logout
- INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES....
- login
- logout
- SELECT SCOPE_IDENTIY()...
- login
- logout
- INSERT INTO MyOtherTable...

There is a different behavior depending on the session, but why? And what means the lot of login/logout events in this case?

**Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)**

Comment: I can't comment on the different behavior but logout/login events will occur the first time a command is executed on reused pooled connection.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman for your answer, yes that's what I think but I don't know why it depends on the session. I don't notice something on the compatibility level upgrade features linked to this issue.